# List of identifiers of ActionScript 3.0 in Adobe Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, list, adobe, notepad++, identifier

I'm looking for a list of identifiers of ActionScript 3.0 . In Adobe Flash, it is possible to change the identifier's color. I want to do the same in notepad++ in langs.xml file. All I need is the list and it seems hard to find one.

Comment: you mean keyword highlighting for the Flash IDE text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file when you install flash called "AsColorSyntax_3.xml" that contains the list you seek.

Find it on windows here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\en\First Run\ActionsPanel\ActionScript_3

Anybody know where on Mac?

Also: 
This project may already be what you want for Notepad ++
http://blog.boogatech.com/improved_actionscript_3_syntax_highlighting_for_notepad_plus_plus/

Comment: Welcome. If you're using Notepad++ for actionscript, maybe you might like FlashDevelop (http://www.flashdevelop.org)

Comment: I have same problem in flashDevelope, right now I fix the notepad++ syntaxcoloring to be the same as my Flash CS4 with your help... : )  this is what I use in CS4: Forgraound:6699ff backgraound:000033 keyword:FFCC00 comments:808080 identifiers:0066ff string:00cc00 .. I have a question, is there any file or files in FlashDevelop like "stylers.xml" and "lang.xml" in notepad++ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flash CS4
edit tab->preferences->ActionScript

You will see the identifiers setting there